# VIM: grep search all files listed in text file

Tags: vim, grep

I have a complected project hierarchy for my FPGA projects. I have written a passer which examines the "Vivado/ISE" project file and returns a file containing a list of all the source file the project users (I then run ctags over this list).

I would like to be able to search this list of files from vim 7.4 without needing to do a whole recursive search through the FPGA library. I can do this from the linux command line using something like:

```
cat ./files.txt | xargs grep -Hn my_function
```

Where ./files.txt contains the list of files I would to search over. However I would like to be able to use vim's internal grep function. I would also like to be able to run this from both Windows and Linux.

Is there an easy way to pass a list of files (contained within a file) to vim's grep ex function?

Comment: When you meant `both Windows and Linux`, did you mean `bash` for Windows?

Comment: @Inian: I develop under both Win10 and multiple flavours of Linux. I do use Cygwin under Windows but ideally I'd like something that doesn't use bash at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use a plugin such as [CtrlSF](https://github.com/dyng/ctrlsf.vim).  But if you insist to do it with Vim alone, you can do something like this:

```
function! Grep(what, where)
    exec join(extend(['vimgrep', a:what],
        \ map(filter(readfile(a:where), 'v:val !=# "" && filereadable(v:val)'),
        \ 'fnameescape(v:val)')))
    copen
endfunction

command! -nargs=+ Grep call Grep(<f-args>)
```

Then you'd just call `:Grep /pattern/ filelist`, instead of `:vimgrep /pattern/ ...`.

Answer (score 2):

First step, populate the argument list with all the files in your list:

```
" in UNIX-like environments
:args `cat files.txt`

" in Windows
:args `type files.txt`
```

Second step, search for `pattern` in the argument list:

```
:vim pattern ##
```

Comment: I really like your answer! But I like Satos answer a little more as it runs faster and does not require cat. Thanks you very much. very helpful!

Comment: Well, you can use `type` on windows instead of `cat` if that's what bothering you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have opened all files in Vim—eg with
`` vim `<files.txt` ``—then you can search all of them with (e.g.)

```
:bufdo g/my_function/
```

If you `:set nu` you'll get line numbers as per 
`grep -nHth`

Comment: I cannot seem to get "vim <./files.txt" working for me maybe the list of files is to long (125) with paths up to 120 characters deep. The error message I get is "Vim: Error reading input, exiting...". I'd really like to be able to perform the search on an already running version of vim.

Comment: Sorry . The editor stripped back quotes I entered, surrounding <files.txt

Comment: Vim \`<files.txt\`

Comment: Thanks this seems close to working but I keep getting spammed with pattern not found. Is there a way to suppress the pattern not found message. Because it makes it very annoying to find where the pattern is found